# The difference between project token and user token - clarification needed

Tags: iron.io

I'd like to make sure that my understanding of concept of user tokens and project tokens is correct.

- When I use API as an admin and authenticate using user token, I can perform any action on projects that I have access to.
- When I use API and authenticate using project token, I can perform any action on that specific project

Am I right? Thanks in advance.

PS. I was trying to find some documentation regarding user roles but I failed. May you please clarify what are associated permissions to user roles you support in iron.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piotr!

1. You are correct, user token gives you an ability to use [IronWorker](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/api/), [IronMQ](http://dev.iron.io/mq/3/reference/api/), and [IronCache](http://dev.iron.io/cache/reference/api/) APIs. You can manage user tokens [here](https://hud-e.iron.io/tokens).
2. In 2017 we introduced Organizational Support which allows companies to manage their users, projects, and clusters. Project-specific tokens allow accessing one or a set of projects in an Iron.io Org Support account without granting project privileges to individual users. The only way to access the project would be to use project-specific token. Users can embed it within their application(s) which call Iron.io services. You can manage project-specific tokens on the Org Support [projects page](https://hud-e.iron.io/org/projects).

P.S.: we are working on improving Org Support documentation and will publish it very soon. Also, the basic Org Support documentation is available [here](http://dev.iron.io/worker/org_support/).